# Blank page in Firefox browser in a Selenium Grid2 setup in C# /Nunit

Tags: firefox, selenium, grid

I get a blank page, when try to open a desired page(google.com) in Firefox browser in Selenium Grid2 using C# piece of code. The FF page does not get closed until I close it manually.The same code works fine for IE and Chrome browsers.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace WebDriverExample
{
public class Class1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Testing
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.Firefox());
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestGoogle()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        } 
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the C# syntax, but I have wrestled with the webdriver not loading the page demon on multiple occasions and have seen a couple of different causes.  There is nothing obviously wrong with your code (though `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(myurl)` seens unnecessarily verbose; in python, it is `driver.get(myurl)`).

Assuming that this isn't the issue, it is most likely a version issue.  When webdriver launches Firefox, it gives it a custom extension binary which has changed with webdriver releases.  Firefox 8 (which is quite widespread these days) needs a fairly new version of the webdriver extension, possibly as new as 2.12.

Besides that, forgive me for the "is it plugged in" question, but I have made the mistake as well: Make sure you have a webdriverobject.get(url) near the top of your test, before you try finding any page elements.